# Water jugs heuristic function for A*

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star

For the classic [water jugs search problem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Water.shtml), even for more than three jugs, which are some admissible functions that can be used for the A* search algorithm?

**Edit:**

I know about http://www.dave-reed.com/csc550.S02/HW/HW4.html , but that function clearly is not consistent.

Comment: You can convert any inconsistent heuristic function to a consistent one. Your heuristic estimate can be: `max(estimate_from_parent - action_cost, estimate_from_this_node)`

Answer (score 3):

There are two general methods how to design an admissible heuristic.
Both work by solving a simpler problem. The heuristic value is then the distance to the goal in the simpler problem.

### 1. Relaxation

The problem is simplified by forgetting negative effects.
For example, if you once had one quart of water, it will be always available when needed.

[A Tutorial on Planning Graph Based Reachability Heuristics](http://rakaposhi.eas.asu.edu/pgSurvey.pdf).

### 2. Abstraction

The problem is simplified by ignoring some details.
For example, a simpler goal could ignore the amount of water in the last jug at the end.

You could store the precomputed heuristic values in a pattern database. The key would be the simpler abstract problem and the value would be the heuristic value.

[A formal introduction](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~ki/teaching/ws0809/aip/aip10.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. These are also shown in AIMA 2nd edition, http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/2nd-ed/. They apply and are effective to the puzzle problem or finding a route form A to B, but these principles shownto be sterile up to now for the jugs problem (personal opinion).

Comment: To apply the heuristics to the jug problem,
read about planning in AIMA. By expressing the actions as a set of preconditions and effects, you could apply any planning algorithm on the problem.